# Between two tables how does one SELECT the table where the id of a specific value exists mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables in my "Hiking" database lets say table 1 is called "Forest" and table 2 is called "Mountain". Both tables have a `FOREIGN KEY` "Trip_id" which is a `PRIMARY KEY` in table "Trip" (or something, this is a made up example) that is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. A trip can either be Mountain or Forest, so the 2 tables do not share any Trip_ids.

I want to `SELECT * FROM` either Forest or Mountain depending on which one has the `Trip_id` of a certain value (lets say 74).

```
SELECT * FROM FOREST OR MOUNTAIN WHERE Trip_id = 74 EXISTS;
```

(I know this code is rubbish and completely wrong but I hope it helps illustrate what I am aiming for).

Comment: They do NOT have the same columns

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they have the same columns, then use `union all`:

```
select m.*
from mountains m
where m.trip_id = 74
union all
select f.*
from forests f
where f.trip_id = 74;
```

Comment: UNION - such an under-appreciated operator :)

Comment: Great comment and my bad but the two tables unfortunately do not have the same columns

Comment: @Cornelius . . . Then just select the common columns you want, with placeholders for the other columns.  A SQL query has a fixed set of columns, so you need to decide on the ones you want.

Comment: Ok, so this is definitely a pretty good answer. However Mountains has a column "Temperature" and Forests has a column "Atmosphere"; and what I want to do, is extract either "Temperature" or "Atmosphere" depending on which, Mountains or Forests contains the Trip_id value 74.
`SELECT Temperature FROM Mountains WHERE Trip_id = 74 OR SELECT Atmosphere FROM Forests WHERE Trip_id = 74;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Forest.Trip_id, Hikes.Trip_id
FROM Forest, Hikes  
WHERE  Forest.Trip_id OR Hikes.Trip_id = 74;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8c9e7/1

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to have all of your locations (or whatever the case is in the actual DB) in one table with a type code. If they are heterogeneous objects then you can use a pattern where you have a single shared table with individual tables for each type that have a 1:1 relationship. For example, `Destinations` (with data that is shared between mountains and forests), with a `destination_id` in the `Hikes` table and then tables for `Mountains` (with data that is specific to mountains) and `Forests`, each of which has a `destination_id` that is also its primary key.

Barring that, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    H.name,
    CASE
        WHEN M.mountain_id IS NOT NULL THEN M.name
        WHEN F.forest_id IS NOT NULL THEN F.name
        ELSE NULL
    END AS destination_name
FROM
    Hikes H
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mountains M ON M.mountain_id = H.destination_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Forests F ON F.forest_id = H.destination_id
WHERE
    H.destination_id = 74
```

You'll continue to run into problems with that structure though, in my experience.